# href javascript:function Targeting a Function in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Let me begin by saying that I don't need a lecture about how I should separate markup from JS. It's not my code, and I don't have a choice.

My problem is that there is a click function on a link triggered by `<a href="javascript:DoFunction(1)">`, however this is within an iFrame and so it's trying to use a DoFunction declaration in the parent window, which is undefined. Is there a way that I can target the iFrame window instead? For example, something like `<a href="javascript:iframe.DoFunction(1)">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `javascript:parent.DoFunction(1)` to access a function in the parent window from a iframe.

To access a function in the iFrame from the parent do something like this:  `document.getElementById('yourframe').contentWindow.yourFunction()`

Comment: That seems to also target the parent window. I want to use the `DoFunction()` declaration from the iFrame window, not the parent window.

Comment: You want to use it in the parent?

Comment: Perfect! `<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.DoFunction();">` Thanks!